# How can I get the field of a Kendo Angular UI Grid column?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a project that uses an Angular 4 Kendo UI Grid.

```
<kendo-grid-column 
    *ngIf="isVisible('fieldName')" 
    field="fieldName" 
    title="Some random field name">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

The `isVisible()` method checks if this columns should be visible or not based on the property I pass to `kendo-grid-column`. I would like to get the field name I specify in `field=fieldName"` dynamically so I don't have to the same text twice for every column.

Something "magical" like this:

```
<kendo-grid-column 
    *ngIf="isVisible(kendo.getField())" 
    field="fieldName" 
    title="Some random field name">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: How many columns do you have and how many of them should have this mechanism?

Comment: @Shai 5 to 10 columns.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `[hidden]` option in the kendo-grid-column

Example:-

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
          <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
            <kendo-grid-column
              field="{{column}}"
              [hidden]="isVisible(column)"
            >

            </kendo-grid-column>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid>
```

**Component file**

```
 public isVisible(field: string): void {
      // based on your condition you can return true to hide 
      // false to show column 
        return false;
    }
```

plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kk8nj4P8k4qY1psexInd?p=preview

Comment: That's not the issue. `*ngIf` if correct. My example works but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: ohh cool !! if you find any good solution post here. I love to learn new way.